# how to save UIImagePicker image with a specific name

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

i capture image from iphone using UIPickerController, then how programatically to save it with specific name, and to call the image later (by using the name), is it any possibilities to change the image size eg. from 100 x 100 pixels to 50 x 50 pixels

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code snippet will save the image to a file:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *anImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, 1.0);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tmpPathToFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/specificImagedName.jpg", path]];

    if([imageData writeToFile:tmpPathToFile atomically:YES]){
          //Write was successful. 
    }
}
```

And then to recall the image from a file:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tmpPathToFile];
[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Finally, [this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5204-resize-image-high-quality.html#post23898) has a method available that you can incorporate into your project to resize the image.