# mailing the screenshot

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

i want to knw is there way to mail the screenshot from the App only i.e without exiting the App.

I have the code to take the screenshot and i have the code to mail(EmailComposer from Apple),but how to attach the screen shot in the mailbody?

please help me out.. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching an image to an email? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093371/attaching-an-image-to-an-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at below URL;

http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/07/how-to-make-your-iphone-app-send-email-with-attachments/

Comment: thanks for your answer.. :)

But the problem is that..the screenshots are saved in photoalbums. :(
how can i pick it from photoalbums without leaving the App??

Comment: see; http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/

Comment: is there any way i can save the screenshot inside my App??

Comment: Thanx dude...it worked.. :)

one more thing, i wanna knw whether the screenshots saved are saved with image name?? if yes, then how can i see them??

Comment: You can see the images on the camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to leave you application, you would have to use a third party library. [Here is some information](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MessageFramework), certain there are a few more out there.

Comment: still the same problem.. :(

how to pick image from photoalbums?? :(

Comment: @user462533 you should update the question because that is not included in it. See this Stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046108/how-to-save-uiimagepicker-image-with-a-specific-name